# How to capture current visual state of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to capture the current visual state of a webpage. I have seen a few different solutions such as HTML2canvas or node-webshot. The problem is that I need to be able to capture the current state of the page rather than just the html from a given url.

E.g if a user goes to a URL and clicks on a few options which change the UI through ajax I need to be able to capture the page as it is to the user at any given time.

Basically I need to take a screenshot ( most likely using javascript ) of the current state of a web page. Im wondering if anyone has an suggestions as to what the best way to go about doing this would be?

Comment: `Basically I need to take a screenshot` then consider [searching for `javascript screenshot`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+screenshot) on this very site first (or on Google). Remember to always go down that road first, thanks!

Comment: technically you could to it with simple canvas and js, but due to browser security you wont be able to see it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using HTML5/Canvas/Javascript to take screenshots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots)